# Xamarin Forms Debug Build to iPhone from PC Causes Crash

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm building my first multi-platform app for android and iOS from my PC and have had no issues on the android side. I also have a mac so that I can do the iOS side of things. Set up my Mac via the microsoft guides, have a developer account and did certificates, provisioning, etc.

So I start by running the app on the iPhone 13 pro max simulator iOS 15.2 - works flawlessly. The app requires BLE functionality so obviously I can't test everything in the simulator. So I debug to my actual iPhone 13 Pro Max iOS15.2 that's plugged into my PC. App boots up and immediately the UI looks kind of strange, there are weird information display bugs that aren't present in the simulator - which looks as expected. I navigate from the main page to the second page, no issues. From the second page to the 3rd page, immediate crash, no errors, no exceptions.

Just this:

```
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a abrt while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================

    0x10446c1e0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0EFE911B-4292-432A-B028-6CEB1EFAFB2A/EMBTuner.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info

    0x104462c5c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0EFE911B-4292-432A-B028-6CEB1EFAFB2A/EMBTuner.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash

    0x10446b728 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0EFE911B-4292-432A-B028-6CEB1EFAFB2A/EMBTuner.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : sigabrt_signal_handler
    0x1f2a5ac10 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>

    0x1b8ea45b8 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1b8ea45ec - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib : <redacted>

    0x1e9b35a54 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : <redacted>
    0x1e9b36230 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : <redacted>
    0x1e9b32ea8 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC : <redacted>
    0x1f2a9832c - /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1f2a8b85c - /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib : <redacted>

    0x181b4b6e0 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x181b68ec8 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x181b5db60 - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1f2a6212c - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : _pthread_wqthread
    0x1f2a61e94 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : start_wqthread


=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1b8ea1cf8):0x1b8ea1ce8  ff 0f 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6 30 41 80 d2 01 10 
00 d4  .._..._.0A......
0x1b8ea1cf8  03 01 00 54 7f 23 03 d5 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91  ...T.#...{......
0x1b8ea1d08  4f 61 
ff 97 bf 03 00 91 fd 7b c1 a8 ff 0f 5f d6  Oa.......{...._.
0x1b8ea1d18  c0 03 5f d6 90 32 80 d2 01 10 00 d4 03 01 00 54  .._..2.........T

The app has been terminated.
```

All I'm doing is clicking a button that calls a push navigation in the same exact way that I do from the first page.

```
private async void Choose_Device_Menu_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListOfDevices(this));
        }
```

on appearing section

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        }
```

Contructor section

```
namespace EMBTuner
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ListOfDevices : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly IDeviceManipulationPage _page;

        public ObservableCollection<IBacGenericDevice> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IBacGenericDevice>(BacCommunication.CurrentRepository.BacDevices);

        public ListOfDevices(IDeviceManipulationPage page)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _page = page;
        }
...
     }
}
```

Again, it's very strange since this works perfectly on the simulator.

SOLUTION:
Adding BLE permissions within info.plist fixed the error. Wish the debugger was a bit smarter in this situation...

Comment: what is happening in the constructor or OnAppearing of `ListOfDevices`?  Do you have any exception handling or logging?

Comment: @Jason Edited post for what in those. I'm obviously new to this so not sure what to add as far as exceptions or logging is concerned. I just don't understand how simulating it on same device and iOS version works fine but it doesn't on the physical device.

Comment: AppCenter.ms has an easy to use crash reporting tool.  Use try/catch around any suspect code for exception handling.  I'd also try moving the initialization of `Items` into a method (not inline) where you can debug it.

Comment: @Jason Thanks! Oddly it never even gets past the navigation line. Setting a catch doesn't do anything because it immediately crashes the moment I step through the Async Naviagtion.

Comment: yes, that's why I suspect something is going wrong in the constructor or Items initialization of the 2nd page.  You can also try instantiating the page on one line and calling the Navigation on another line, to narrow it down